# Difference between PySpark functions write.parquet vs write.format('parquet')

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, parquet

In PySpark DataFrames can be saved in two ways, irrespective of the data it contains

```
df.write.format('parquet').save(<path>)
```

and

```
df.write.parquet(<path>)
```

What is the difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the [implementation of `parquet("path")`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/85d8d62216d3b830cc5af3dec05422a9cda4cea0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L791) and you will see that it just calls `format("parquet").save("path")`.

Comment: thanks but I was checking this and didn't saw it. Is this what you mean for implementation? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet

Comment: line 791 here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala